# Alternative to Dixit Odyssey voting boards+pegs

Tags: dixit, dixit-odyssey

I recently bought Dixit Odyssey to enable more players at the same time. One thing about Odyssey that I absolutely don't like, is the new voting system with the cards and pegs. It's a lot harder to tell who's already placed a vote and we generally end up needlessly waiting for everyone to vote (when everyone already has).

We'd really like to go back to using upside down numbered tokens to vote with. Where can I get those for 12 players (in the right colors)?

Comment: If you ask the other players who is still thinking it will help speed up the votes as players will realize others are waiting on them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't official tokens for more than 7 players. Instead, you can have the rule that people hold their hands over their voting cards on the table to indicate readiness. That makes it easy to tell if someone is still deciding, and if you hold the voting card face down against the table it stops the pegs falling out.

Comment: We found the card+peg system to be much easier to use than the tokens. After laying the picture cards face up in a line all players take their voting card and peg out of sight (under the table, hidden behind their hands, etc), place the peg in the hole they choose, then grip the card in a way that their hands hide all the holes (and the peg) and hold their hands over to the center of the table. This way we can all see who is ready, but the votes remain secret until everyone reveals them.

Answer (score 0):

When playing with such many players, especially when some of them are playing for the first time, we have one person holding one part of the box and collecting all the voting cards - when someone is ready he put it here.

Box is usually hold above the heads of all other sitting people (when playing with so many players there always is someone not sitting by the table so it is not the problem), to noone see the the answers. Usually the person holding the box is the one checking all the answers then, and tracking the score - it is more easy to sort and check all the voting cards in the box. Many of the players usually don't want to know the exact scoring mechanisms, so it is fine for them.

One disadvantage of this solution is when people stars to throw their voting cards to the box, inside of putting them gently. If they are doing so, sometimes, the pegs are moving out - anyway you just need to tell people to be more gentle.

Answer (score 0):

**For each player, any face-down writing surface will do.**

The standalone version of Dixit Odyssey's 12 player boards are annoying to use.  Unfortunately the face down chits that come with the basic Dixit version are numbered 1 through 6 to accommodate 6 players only.  For games of 7 or more players, consider replacing these chits with an opaque writing surface. Players can write their numbered guess on it, then turn it face down and rest their writing utensil on it.  The storyteller can see this, and call out, "Pencils down, everyone?" as necessary to move things along.

Dry erase boards and markers work spectacularly for this purpose. I have used the colored dry erase boards from Wits and Wagers, as well as the dry erase pads from Telestrations Party pack.  Players don't even need to have their own colors and those colors don't need to match their bunny color (and whatever extra pieces are acting as player tokens for the additional players).  When scoring players can move thier own piece or tell someone to move their piece - confusion over that is minimal.

For people who own the standalone Odyssey version of Dixit, that has the board with 12 numbered slots for cards so this next part isn't necessary.  For people who have the basic Dixit (with expansions hopefully) they can again use use any writing surface to represent slots 7-12 when displaying the additional cards beyond 6.

Answer (score -2):

There's a wide variety of cards that have numbers on them. The cheapest is probably simple playing cards; you can get a deck for about a dollar, so three dollars will accommodate twelve players (one suit for each player). You could also buy index cards and make your own; it would be cheaper and more customized, but more work, and the cards wouldn't take as much abuse.

Comment: @Joe what Acccum is trying to convey may be that decks of playing cards can be used because they are numbered and opaque.  And i guess jacks and better can be used for games with 11+.  there are only 4 suits per deck so additional decks can be used to cover more players.  Acccum build out your Answer a little and I will upvote because it's actually very practical given how many Dixit players will also have decks of playing cards laying around.